# laravel : passed data not be showed

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i am new in laravel i made CRUD for some services. when i try to edit any one i have this error

> `Missing required parameter for [Route: services.update] [URI: dashboard/services/{service}] [Missing parameter: service].`

my code to take data to edit it
 `<a href="{{route('services.edit', $service->id)}}">`

my code in editing page `{{ $service->id }}`

and when i write in form to update in the editing page `action="{{ route('services.update', $service->id) }}"`
i got the error

and the code of edit in controller

```
public function edit(Service $service)
    {
        return view('dashboard.EditService', compact('service'));
    }
```

in my rout page >>

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'/dashboard' ], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('dashboard/index');
    });
    
    Route::resource('/services', 'App\Http\Controllers\ServiceController');
});
```

Comment: How did you define the route in the web.php file

Comment: Can you show us web.php ,your view and controller.

Answer (score -1):

'*Service*' and '*Services*' (with an *'s'* at the end) are different things according to laravel.

Try change your web.php file route parameter.

**Before**

```
Route::get('dashboard/services/{service}', [Controller::class, 'function']);
```

**After**

```
Route::get('dashboard/services/{services}', [Controller::class, 'function']);
```